# How to validate SharePoint form field using regular expression?

Tags: validation

I am using SharePoint form field.
I used regular expression for allowing only numbers not less than zero, but it is allowing alphabets and throwing error if I enter number less than zero.

```
function numericvalidation(validatefield, id) {

 var inputVal = id;


              var numericReg = /[^abc][^1-9]+$/;

              var isvalidinput = numericReg.test(inputVal);
              if (!isvalidinput) {
                  $("div[id*='divestimateddurationmaonths']").text(validatefield + "\n" + "must be greater than zero and  should be numeric");
                  $("div[id*='divestimateddurationmaonths']").attr("style", "color:red;font-size:13px");

              }
              return isvalidinput;


          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your required function

```
    function validatenumber(el) {
    var regex = /^[0-9]*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;    // allow only numbers [0-9] 
     if( !regex.test(el.value) ) {
      alert('invalid value');
     }
   }
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qd7BL/) jsfiddle for more details

Please let me know if you have any question?

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Comment: Hi,thak u I already used it but its is taking alphabets also

Comment: which alphabets?? i see working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/qd7BL/